# Why can't I use image src function after I implement background in #bg?

Tags: html, css

```
#bg{
    background: url("adventure.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
   }

<img src="sword.png" alt="sword" width="100px" height="100">
```

Why can't I use image src function after I implement background in #bg? Should I just use background-image instead? But even if I changed to background-image, the image is not showing up, what should I do?

Comment: What do you mean? Using a background image and an image element are two completely different things and they shouldn't interfere with each other. Please show us a minimal, concrete and verifiable example—that'll help a lot with arriving at a solution.

Comment: You can't combine `html` and `css` fragments in the same block-code... what are you trying to do?

Comment: `#bg` is an `id` tag, as in `<img id='bg' ... />`  where as `.bg` would be used as `<img class='bg'` ... />

Comment: how does that #bg ID relate to the image? there's NOTHING to tie those two together.

Comment: I put  #bg in <div id="bg"></div> , it is fine like this right? then, why I can't use <img src="sword.png" alt="sword" width="100px" height="100"> after the </div> .. my image is hide under the background: url("") that I used .. how do I show it up on screen ..

Comment: something is missing you should put more code, there NO problem with what you show, the problem should be from something else

Comment: its <noidea>, but try to add img position:relative, and z-index:9

Comment: got it guys. thanks allot. I used z-index: -1 in my #bg{}

Answer (score 0):

```css
#bg {
background-color : green;
}

.bg {
background-color : red;
}
```

```html
<div id='bg' style='height:50px; width : 50px;'></div>
<div class='bg' style='height:50px; width : 50px;'></div>
```